# Swift programmatically set view constraint error log

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, constraints

I have `UIViewController` with a couple of views and one of them is UIView that contains ads view(AdMob).

This is how I set the view `Constraint`:

```
selectBtn.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 50.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0, right: 10.0))
selectBtn.centerXToSuperview()
        
statusLabel.anchor(top: selectBtn.bottomAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0, right: 10.0))

fileSizeLabel.anchor(top: statusLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0, right: 10.0))

adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -50.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))

imageView.anchor(top: fileSizeLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: adView.topAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0))
```

The `adView` is in full size but under the view because of the padding that I add(I want to show the `adview` only when the ad is available).

When the ad is available I call this code(to bring the `adview` to be visible):

```
adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001c34af0 UIView:0x7fbdf040e130.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x60000061ae60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom + 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001c3c2d0 UIView:0x7fbdf040e130.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x60000061ae60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001c34af0 UIView:0x7fbdf040e130.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x60000061ae60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom + 50   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is the anchor method I'm using:

```
open func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {
        
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()
    
    if let top = top {
        anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
    }
    
    if let leading = leading {
        anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
    }
    
    if let bottom = bottom {
        anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
    }
    
    if let trailing = trailing {
        anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
    }
    
    if size.width != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
    }
    
    if size.height != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
    }
    
    [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach{ $0?.isActive = true }
    
    return anchoredConstraints
}
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When the ad is availabele you should play with created bottom constraints here

```
adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -50.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))
```

but as you create another bottom constraint here

```
adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))
```

it conflicts with the old 1 , so you should have an instance vaiable

```
var bottomCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and supply nil initially here for the bottom anchor

```
adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom:nil, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -50.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))
```

with addition of it like this

```
bottomCon = adView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant:50)
bottomCon.isActive = true
```

after this when you need to show the ad play with constant valie

```
bottomCon.constant = 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing conflicting constraints for `adView`.

```
adView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: -50.0, right: 0.0), size: .init(width: view.width, height: 50.0))
```

Providing bottom constrait along with padding. Delete one of them, it will work fine.